# How can I install the [embed.diagrams.net] service on my private network?

Tags: draw.io

I want to use draw.io in Bookstack on offline environment.

I install drawio service via docker (refer https://github.com/jgraph/docker-drawio), and modify Bookstack config DRAWIO=http://[my host]/?embed=1&proto=json&spin=1&configure=1
but it is not working, I find they are different, I wonder what has possible can install the [embed.diagrams.net] service on my private network?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following URL worked for me:

```
http://[my host]:8080/?embed=1&proto=json&spin=1
```

It seems like you had an additional `configure=1` parameter. Note that only providing the parameter `embed=1` also results in what appears to be the same web page.