# How to configure Bookstack with draw.io in an offline Docker environment?

Tags: docker, draw.io

I try to set up an offline version of bookstack (https://hub.docker.com/r/linuxserver/bookstack) with draw.io (https://hub.docker.com/r/jgraph/drawio).

DrawIO:

```
docker run -p 8080:8080 jgraph/drawio
```

Bookstack:

```
docker run -e APP_URL=<URL> -e DB_HOST=<DB_HOST> -e DB_USER=<DB_USER> -e DB_PASS=<DB_PASS> -e DB_DATABASE=<DB_DATABASE> -e DRAWIO="http://<HOST IP>:8080/?embed=1&proto=json&spin=1" linuxserver/bookstack
```

Bookstack and DrawIO work just fine, except for one issue: Whenever I click on "Insert/edit drawing" in a bookstack page I just get a blank page. Opening the console in Firefox (with F12) I see the following error:

> 'Content Security Policy: The page's settings blocked the loading of a
> resource at http://127.0.0.1:8080/?embed=1&proto=json&spin=1
> ("frame-src")'

Can anyone tell me what I did wrong? I followed this tutorial: https://www.bookstackapp.com/docs/admin/other-config/#custom-diagramsnet-url.

I also already tried this:

[How can I install the [embed.diagrams.net] service on my private network?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74272060/how-can-i-install-the-embed-diagrams-net-service-on-my-private-network)

with the configure=1 parameter in the URL.

Thank you very much!